# How to add to the value of a text field

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have the form below.  Using the buttons, the value in the text field should be increase or decreased.  the decrease button works fine, but the increase button simply appends a '10' to the end of the number, so `100` will become `10010`, rather than `110`.  Can someone let me know how to fix this?

```
<form name="hello" id="hello">
<table border=0>
<tr>
<td width=200>
<input type=text id="input" style="height: 30px; width: 200px" name=amount value=5>
</td>
<td>
<table border=0>
<tr height=12><td width=20>
<input type=button value="+" style="height: 15px; width: 25px; text-align:center; vertical-align:center; font-size:8px;" onClick="javascript:this.form.amount.value+=10;">
</td></tr>
<tr height=12><td width=20>
<input type=button value="-" style="height: 15px; width: 25px; text-align:center; vertical-align:center; font-size:8px;" onClick="javascript:this.form.amount.value-=10;">
</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your javascript is treating it like a string concatenation. Parse the value into an int, do the math, and then set the value.

The onClick for your `+` button

```
onClick="javascript: this.form.amount.value = parseInt(this.form.amount.value, 10) + 10;"
```

Comment: Use the two argument version of `parseInt`, you don't want user input being treated as octal or hex.

Comment: @Quentin, forgot about that. Thanks.

Comment: Note to OP: the two-argument version of parseInt would be `parseInt(this.form.amount.value, 10)`, which says "I want this to be a decimal number." The second argument to `parseInt` is the notation system (e.g., `10` is decimal, `16` is hexadecimal). Also that number shouldn't be confused with the `+10` or `-10` that you add on afterwards.

Comment: Also the `javascript:` (copied from the question), in this context, is a useless [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label)

Answer (score 1):

Here's some code that will work:

```
<form name="hello" id="hello">
<table border=0>
<tr>
<td width=200>
<input type=text id="input" style="height: 30px; width: 200px" name=amount value=5>
</td>
<td>
<table border=0>
<tr height=12><td width=20>
<input type=button value="+" style="height: 15px; width: 25px; text-align:center; vertical-align:center; font-size:8px;" onClick="javascript:this.form.amount.value=parseInt(this.form.amount.value,10)+10;">
</td></tr>
<tr height=12><td width=20>
<input type=button value="-" style="height: 15px; width: 25px; text-align:center; vertical-align:center; font-size:8px;" onClick="javascript:this.form.amount.value=parseInt(this.form.amount.value,10)-10;">
</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

parseInt() is required.

Use this

```
    <form name="hello" id="hello">
<table border=0>
<tr>
<td width=200>
<input type=text id="input" style="height: 30px; width: 200px" name=amount value=5>
</td>
<td>
<table border=0>
<tr height=12><td width=20>
<input type=button value="+" style="height: 15px; width: 25px; text-align:center; vertical-align:center; font-size:8px;" onClick="javascript: this.form.amount.value = parseInt(this.form.amount.value) + 10;">
</td></tr>
<tr height=12><td width=20>
<input type=button value="-" style="height: 15px; width: 25px; text-align:center; vertical-align:center; font-size:8px;" onClick="javascript:this.form.amount.value-=10;">
</td></tr>
</table>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

The code for the onClick event should read: `javascript:this.form.amount.value=Number(this.form.amount.value)+10;`

Javascript doesn't have a string concatenation operator like PHP, so you have to cast it as a number before you do any arithmetic on it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to typecast `this.form.amount.value` to Integer, else it will be treated as a String. Use `parseInt()` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is interpreting the value of the text field as a string. You can use parseInt() to have the value turned into a number.

```
javascript:this.form.amount.value=parseInt(this.form.amount.value, 10)+10;
```